# Android Edit Text error overlaps Actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml

Does anybody have an idea how to display an error message behind the actionbar?

[image]

Please check this is my xml file of design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_second"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextlastname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="lastname"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1000dp"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: if you are using relative layout then use tag >>
android:layout_below="..."

Comment: Try this add android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" to the parent layout

Comment: @Raghavendra i try to android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" but not working

Comment: Post  your layout file

Comment: Please Post your XML Code

Comment: Why is your `paddingBottom="1000dp"`?

Comment: paddingBottom for use scroll to top of the actionbar. @KamranAhmed

Answer (score 1):

**I got a solution of this issue please try this**

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (yourEditText.getError() != null) {
                yourEditText.setError(null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing validation of all edit text at once(using || in if block) do the validation one by one(use && instead of ||) which will automatically focus your lastname code below action bar with error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `RelativeLayout` as your main parent layout then change it to `LinearLayout` and set orientation to `Vertical`.